# Apply Outisde Borders at selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering on how can I apply Outside borders (Range A1:M4) without placing in a code that has "worksheet" or "sheets" in it .
For example

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:I10").BorderAround 
[INDENT].LineStyle = xlContinuous[/INDENT] 
[INDENT].Weight = xlThick[/INDENT] 
End With
```

OR

```
With Sheet1.Range("B8:I10").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
End With
```

This is because the Sheet has not been set yet (as of how my formatting for User interface will be) and I am using VBA module

Answer (score 0):

You can try assign the newly created worksheet in a variable. This will return you the worksheet name.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub ReturnWorkSheetName()

Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set MainWorksheet = MainWorkBook.ActiveSheet

MsgBox MainWorksheet.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                FormatControlCell.Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin;

                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalDown].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalUp].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
                FormatControlCell.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
```

Comment: FormatControlCell is a range Object